# The requested URL /manifest.json was not found on this server

Tags: django, file-permissions

While configuring gcm using izooto, I've placed the files in the root folder and added the read permissions for all the users. But, the file is not accessible [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cCu4S.png)

I'm using django, nginx on server. I've tried restarting the server.

Comment: But what do you mean, you placed them in the 'root folder'? The root folder of what? Remember Django is an application framework, it does not serve files directly.